# Get response stream convert it to ASCII

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This code snippet is sending some values to an SMS gateway.  Then the SMS gateway gives us some values.  I need to catch that value and write it to a file.

When I send a SMS this value shown:

> b6c56c74-03b0-11e2-b28c-00145e7e986e

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(
    "http://base.mygateway.com/api/mt?msisdn=" + mobileNo
    + "&body=" + msgOut
    + "&sender=" + shortcode
    + "&key=abcdefghi&product_id=10023&operator="
    + oppp + "&country=UnitedStates");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
byte[] ary = new byte[1000];
response.GetResponseStream().Read(ary, 0, (int) response.ContentLength);
```

I wanted to convert to ASCII value that comes from `GetResponseStream()`. I have no idea how to do that. In the above code I take the values... how do I convert them?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to convert a `byte[]` to the wanted encoding.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ary);
```

You will want to ensure that the values returned from the `WebRequest` are correctly encoded as well. For this purpose you may want to use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instead, as it has an `Encoding` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),Encoding.UTF8)
                 .ReadToEnd();
```